# xpath to find rows containing 1 tr and 1 th

Tags: html, xpath

I need help writing xpath to find rows in a table which contains only 1 th and 1 td only

example html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>test</th>
            <td>abc</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>test1</th>
            <td>abc</td>
            <td>abc</td>
        </tr>
            <th>test2</th>
            <td>abc</td>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

for this html I expect only the first row and the last, if the row contains anything other than th and td it should be skipped

`'//table/tr[th and td]'`  I reached this xpath but this will include repeated `td` doesn't filter if the row contains other `<a` or anything

Comment: your input html need fixing. <tr> is missing for the last bit and the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's doable - not very elegant, but works. I extended your sample html to introduce a few more problematic nodes:

```
test = """
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>test</th>
            <td>abc</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>test1</th>
            <td>abc</td>
            <td>abc</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>test2</th>
            <td>abc</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <a>test3</a>
            <td>abcd</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>test4</td>
            <td>abcd</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>    """

import lxml.html
doc = lxml.html.fromstring(test)
good_tags = ['th','td']
targs = doc.xpath('//tr')
for targ in targs:
    tr = targ.xpath('.//*')
    if len(tr)==2 and (tr[0].tag != tr[1].tag) and tr[0].tag in good_tags and tr[1].tag in good_tags:            
        print(lxml.html.tostring(targ).decode())
```

Output:

```
<tr>
            <th>test</th>
            <td>abc</td>
        </tr>

<tr>
            <th>test2</th>
            <td>abc</td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

One liner XPath :

```
//tr[count (./*)=2 and count(./th)=1 and count(./td)=1]
```